# How to display selected HTML table row value into input type radio and checkbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a HTML table which loads information from a MySQL database and a form to add, update and load the selected row of that tabla. Some rows of this table are hidden in order to fit the table and the form into the HTML doc.

When a row is selected or clicked the fields in form are loaded with information contained in the visible and invisible rows of the table, but what I don't know how to do is set the inputs type radio and checkbox as checked. I mean, if a row has a value 3 in the hidden column "Status", how do I do to set radio input as checked, where "Widower" is in the form. also, if some checkboxes are true (or value 1) how do I set them as checked properly?
Any idea?

```
SAMPLE OF HTML TABLE
+----+---------+---------+---------+-----+--------+----------+
| id | Name    | L-name  | Month   | Day | Status | Category |
+----+---------+---------+---------+-----+--------+----------+
| 1  | Luis    | Lopez   | January | 7   | 1      | 3        |
| 2  | Carlos  | Cooper  | March   | 12  | 3      | 1        |
| 3  | Ana     | Snow    | December| 3   | 2      | 1        |
+----+---------+---------+---------+-----+--------+----------+
```

I summarized the code a bit, and it works, but radio and checkboxes are needed in the script:

```
<!--Here's the form-->
<div class="fields">
<form action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information: </legend>
            Name: <input type="text" required name="nombre" id="name"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" required name="apellido" id="l-name"><br>
            <label>Birthday: </label>
            <select name="mes" id="month">
                <option value="">Choose month</option>
                <option value="January ">January </option>
                <option value="February ">February </option>
                <!--And so on till December-->
            </select>
            Day: <input type="number" name="dia" min="1" max="31" value="1" id="day"><br>
            Status:<input type="radio" name="estado" value="1" id="stage" checked> Single
                   <input type="radio" name="estado" value="2"> Married
                   <input type="radio" name="estado" value="3"> Widower
                   <input type="radio" name="estado" value="4"> Divorced<br><br>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Category:</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="categoria" value="1" id="tag"> Gentleman
                    <input type="radio" name="categoria" value="2" id="tag"> Lady
                    <input type="radio" name="categoria" value="3" id="tag"> young
                    <input type="radio" name="categoria" value="4" id="tag"> Child<br>
            </fieldset>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Other Information: </legend>
        Available: 
            <input type="radio" name="yes" value="1">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="no" value="0">No<br><br>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Skill:</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="1"> HTML
                <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="2"> JS
                <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="3"> Python
                <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="4"> JAVA
        </fieldset>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Agregar">
    </fieldset>
</form> 
</div> <!--End field-->

<!--Here's the form-->
<div class="tabla">
    <table id="table">
        <thead>
            <th style="display:none";>id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th style="display:none";>Other</th>
            <th style="display:none";>Other</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="display:none";><?php echo $user['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user['nombre']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user['apellido']; ?></td>
                    <td style="display:none";><?php echo $user['mes']; ?></td>
                    <td style="display:none";><?php echo $user['dia']; ?></td>
                    <td style="display:none";><?php echo $user['estado']; ?></td>
                    <td style="display:none";><?php echo $user['categoria']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div> <!--End tabla-->

<!--JS to load row information to form using id-->
<script>
    var table = document.getElementById('table'),rIndex;
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){
        table.rows[i].onclick = function(){
            rIndex = this.rowsIndex;
            document.getElementById("name").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("l-name").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("month").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("day").value = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("stage").value = this.cells[5].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("tag").value = this.cells[6].innerHTML;
        };
    }
</script>
```

I've also tried something where I've created some MySQL rows to save the skills named as skill1, skill2, skill3 and so on but no succeed:

```
<!--radioboxes skills-->
<input type="checkbox" id="php" value="php"> PHP
<input type="checkbox" id="python" value="python"> PYTHON
<input type="checkbox" id="html" value="html"> HTML
<input type="checkbox" id="js" value="js"> JS

<!--hidden rows of the table that load the MySQL data-->
<td style="display:none";><?php echo $user['php']; ?></td>
<td style="display:none";><?php echo $user['python']; ?></td>
<td style="display:none";><?php echo $user['html']; ?></td>
<td style="display:none";><?php echo $user['js']; ?></td>

<!--js code-->
....
document.getElementById("php" + this.cells[4].innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase()).checked = true;
document.getElementById("python" + this.cells[5].innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase()).checked = true;
document.getElementById("html" + this.cells[6].innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase()).checked = true;
document.getElementById("js" + this.cells[7].innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase()).checked = true;
```

Comment: please provide minimum code

Comment: Please Clear the thing. It's not clear what do you want to know?

Comment: I don't understand your questin. Are you asking to to toggle the visibility of certain rows based on which checkboxes are clicked?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my English isn't so good. I got better my question. I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` attribute should be unique. There are four `input` elements with the same `id` so this is wrong:

```
<input type="radio" name="categoria" value="1" id="tag"> Gentleman
<input type="radio" name="categoria" value="2" id="tag"> Lady
<input type="radio" name="categoria" value="3" id="tag"> young
<input type="radio" name="categoria" value="4" id="tag"> Child
```

I assume that `<?php echo $user['categoria']; ?>` evaluates to some string value from known list of values and so I propose to change `id`s in this way:

```
<input type="radio" name="categoria" value="1" id="tag_gentleman"> Gentleman
<input type="radio" name="categoria" value="2" id="tag_lady"> Lady
<input type="radio" name="categoria" value="3" id="tag_young"> young
<input type="radio" name="categoria" value="4" id="tag_child"> Child
```

Then you can change this JS code:

```
document.getElementById("tag").value = this.cells[6].innerHTML;
```

Into this:

```
document.getElementById("tag_" + this.cells[6].innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase()).checked = true;
```

This should target and set proper radio inputs. You can set up other radio and checkbox inputs in this fashion. Also, you might want to clear state of all checkboxes before setting them up for another row.

EDIT:

I've made corrections to my code above:
1. fixed `trim` functions - I used it in PHP way instead of JS;
2. added `toLowerCase` and renamed all `id`s to lowercase.

There is [working example in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1no8dcg/1/) based on your example from PasteBin.

EDIT 2:

[Working example in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1no8dcg/2/) of translating multiple value list to checkboxes.

Comment: Well, I did what you wrote but set : tag_1, tag_2 and so on to each radio input, and then changed `document.getElementById("tag_" + trim(this.cells[6].innerHTML)).checked = true;` in the JS but still doesn't work. It does nothing!

Comment: @Einnerlink, why did you set ids to `tag_1, tag_2`? Does `this.cells[6].innerHTML` evaluate to numbers? I proposed names like `tag_Gentleman` because I assume that `this.cells[6].innerHTML` evaluates to strings.

Comment: My bad! Anyway, I've just done it as you suggested but it doesn't work either! I had to write a small example here [pastebin] (https://pastebin.com/84Bs3hcZ)

Comment: @Einnerlink, I've updated my answer: fixed error with trim function and modified your sample code from pastebin so now it works. Make sure to carefully study differences between your code and mine - I've corrected `id`s, added radio button reset and lower case conversion.

Comment: Now I realized that I have situaciotions where a row could have severals checkbox's value, i.e. if I have some checkboxes (PHP, Python, HTML...), a row could show a user knows some of them not just one. And here's where the code need something else.

Comment: @Einnerlink, I've added new code example at the bottom of my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Yeah that really works!!! But now I have gone further loading a MySQL db into the table to be displayed in the form. So, I'm dealing how to adapt your example with no succeed. I guess I have to write another question to be clear.

Comment: By the way, if I assign an id to each checkbox that does not have any relation with the others id="Python" id="PHP", and I enable a column for each of them, how would the code look like cos I've tried your 2 examples and it does not work. I added something else to the question at the end.